# Selenium tests using static date

Tags: python, date, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing up some Selenium tests for my site, and I'd like to test the date/timepickers I have, primarily to make sure that the code I put in to prevent users from putting in dates out of order works.

However, I've realized that the tests I have won't work the way I want them to if it's close to midnight, as the times I'm passing in will wrap to the next day, and be earlier than the current time rather than later, or vice versa.

Is it possible to run these tests as if it were a specific date/time?

Comment: What are you using for your date objects? A time that's close to midnight should not be "wrapped" to the next day unless that's what you want it to do. Are you passing in 24-hour times into a 12-hour objects?

Comment: Rather than single input fields with a datetimepicker, I have a number of input fields with a datepicker each paired with an input field with a timepicker. So if it's 11:30pm and I want to set the time to 1 hour from now, it will go to 12:30am, which is actually 23 hours earlier. I'm fine with this behaviour for the site, but it will make tests fail if they're run close to midnight on either end

Comment: That sounds like reasonable time behavior: if I increased an hour input from 11:30 PM by an hour I expect it to automatically switch to 12:30 AM. You may need to re-consider your test cases. You may need to provide day information as well if going from one day to another is an issue.

Comment: The thing is, if I want to test the time constraints, I need to be able to try changing the time to sometime before and some time after the current time (since one constraint is that the times can't be in the past). I can make these adjustments smaller to minimize the window in which the tests won't work, but I feel like it's bad to have tests that fail for reasons other than "There's a problem in the code"

Comment: Those are reasonable tests, but if you're only comparing the time values and ignoring the date component, I wouldn't consider them to be valid tests in the first place in the context of past/present. You'd run into a similar problem on any of the edge cases, such as new years eve, new years day, the beginning of time, ....

Comment: Since my dates and times are split into two inputs, I can't change both date and time at once. It's certainly an edge case, but I feel it would be better to be able to reliably test how it is handled by testing using a specific date/time, rather than occasionally running into it by accident

Comment: I guess my question would be why you're testing them (date and time) separately, when the problem essentially requires you to take the two components and treat it as a single object. Are you ever going to run into a situation where your date component is not considered?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. For some reason I was thinking about things sort of the wrong way. That being said, I still think it would probably be good to be able to keep the date constant to have less volatile tests

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the date/time constant for the purpose of your tests, you can just hardcode the date/time and passing it to the methods you want to test. If "hardcoding a date" doesn't feel right you could hardcode the specific sequence of actions that a browser might go through, to pick a particular date that happens to be static.

After all, you are testing whether your method correctly determines whether a date is before or after another date; how the input is provided is not relevant.

Comment: That's mostly what I've decided to do, though it leaves the initial "Not in the past" restriction untested. This also doesn't really answer my question of whether what I'm asking is possible or not

Comment: `you can just hardcode the date/time and passing it to the methods you want to test`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? From what I've seen, Selenium is pretty much just black-box testing...

Comment: Simulate the date-picking. Explicitly call your checking methods. I don't know what your needs are, but if you're using Selenium then presumably you're dealing with a website? If you need to explicitly invoke javascript that should be supported.